# Link error with bootstrap and datatable

Tags: codeigniter, datatable, bootstrap-modal

Hi I'm using the following links in my program which is written in codeigniter, but I'm getting error.

1.('assests/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')

2.('assests/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css')

For Js :

1.('assests/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js')

2.('assests/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')

3.('assests/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')

4.('assests/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js')

The errors I'm getting are:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Same error for nine times it is showing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide your code where you declare this assets, base_url, and .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not giving the correct path while rendering the view. 
Please change the as follows.

`<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assests/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" ></script>`

Follow the same for other resources.

`base_url()` will display your site url.

I assume you have already set the `base_url` in config file under `application/config`.

If not, update as follows. `$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/your-project-name/";`

Hope this can help you.